# Analogue Tape how long do I have to record?

Tags: divisibility, estimation

If I have 1200ft (feet) of tape.

How long will I be able to record for at 7.5ips (inches per second)

Thank you

Comment: I tried to divide the 1200ft by 1rounding up to 12inches (1foot) and somehow minus the 4.5 inches, but I'm completely lost, have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 foot is 12 inches. we have 1200 ft so 14400 inches. we have 7.5 inches per second.  14400 inches/7.5 inches per second = 1920 seconds.